# Table layout: broken in Firefox & didn't use 100% width of panel?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'm playing with the [Table Layout](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Table) of ExtJS 4.2.1. You can see the result [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WWqtZ/).

Basically what I expected is to the table use 100% width of the panel to apply correctly the colspan.

Also if you look with Firefox it is broken so maybe I'm using this layout in the wrong way?

Example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Table Layout',
    width: 300,
    height: 150,
    layout: {
        type: 'table',
        // The total column count must be specified here
        columns: 3
    },
    defaults: {
        // applied to each contained panel
        bodyStyle: 'padding:20px'
    },
    items: [{
        html: 'Cell B content',
        colspan: 2,
        xtype: 'panel'
    },{
        html: 'Cell C content',
        xtype: 'panel'
    },{
        html: 'Cell D content',
        xtype: 'panel'
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ExtJS table layout is supposed to work just like an HTML table.  If you create an HTML table with the config you supplied above, you get similar results. (see http://jsfiddle.net/h6J3J/1/)

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Cell B content</td>
    <td>Cell C content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell D content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You see the results that you do because the first column in the first row (with colspan 2) does not have two columns in the row below it to span over.

To get the table to be 100% the width of the panel, you can use the tableAttrs property:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Table-cfg-tableAttrs

```
layout: {
    type: 'table',
    columns: 3,
    tableAttrs: {
        style: {
            width: '100%'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Even adjusting the second row the result is different from the table markup: http://jsfiddle.net/WWqtZ/1/. This also not explains why the table don't use 100% of the panel width.

Comment: I added a little bit to my answer to cover the 100% width.  Here's my HTML markup which mimics your adjustments.  It behaves the same way.  (http://jsfiddle.net/h6J3J/2/)

What kind of layout are you trying to accomplish?  Perhaps a table layout isn't the best approach for your case.

Comment: Probably I will use another layout. I'm using table just to test and see how it works :-)

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific.  The tableAttrs property needs to be added to the layout config object:  http://jsfiddle.net/WWqtZ/3/

Comment: Nice! Answer accepted. Just FF that still broke the layout with the panel title.